# Two-way binding to static property in static class

Tags: xaml, binding, static, static-class, two-way

Is that seriously NOT possible? I have solutions to bind one-way to properties in static classes and certainly i have solutions to bind two-way to static properties in non-static classes... but...

I mean, the workaround is easy, i can just make my static class to a singleton with a static instance getter (see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/257a41be-8168-401c-a915-cdc44e195a3f/)), but isn't there a proper way??

my class looks something like that:

```
public static class TestClass
{
  public static string TestProp {get; set;}
}
```

And now please assume that i properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the "normal" way in the setter (omitted for simplicity).

How should the XAML look like to bind two-way to this property?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

this answer may help:
[wpf static binding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371281/wpf-static-binding-question)
or this:
[Binding to static class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862455/binding-wpf-textblock-to-static-class-property)

in short, your case would look something like:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static whatever:TestClass.TestProperty}, Path=.}
```

Comment: i think this doesn't work for two way binding - though i have no time to test now. I will test it tomorrow.

Comment: This throws the exception "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath." Thus it is not an answer to my question :(

Comment: fixed the Path.  sorry about that.  by the way, how do you do property-changed notification in a static class?

Comment: well, actually i needed to change the value only in the gui, so i didn't implement the property-changed. Which, now when you ask, would be not so easy as well. However, your fix (Path=.) lets the project compile, but still, the changes made in the gui are not reflected in my data...